# ubuntu 20.04 applications menu has no icons, but can launch softwares from the side bar tray that still has icons

Tags: updates, icons, menu, 20.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 yesterday, The update ran successfully and rebooted the system.
As soon as I logged in to the desktop, I clicked on the applications menu and there were no icons. I tried searching for existing installed software but it kept showing me "Searching . . . ".
I went to the frequents tab and the menu crashed and some notification about an internal error has been detected was shown.

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? Officially, users are not currently notified yet through the Software Updater about the possibility to upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. To fix it, type:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

If you have trouble logging in after reboot, do:

1. `ctrl + alt + f2`
2. Login in
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt upgrade`
5. `sudo reboot`

Good luck.

Comment: Worked perfectly, didn't have any login trouble as ubuntu -- right after reinstallation -- notified me about an important system upgrade and i ran and installed all the updates.

Comment: my dock bar show wrong icon of application, (but desktop show right).
this solution solved my trouble. thanks alot.