# Toolbar Icons Missing in 20.04 LTS

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, evolution

After upgrading to 20.04 LTS, I find that a number of applications are missing toolbar icons. Applications that display a tool icon in menus are also missing some icons. I have noticed missing icons in: Evolution ver. 3.36.1-2; AisleRiot (solitaire) ver. 3.22.9; KMahjongg ver. 0.9; and I suspect that any program which relies on system-level icons may exhibit the same behavior.

Evolution supplies *some* of its own icons; these are found in /etc/share/Evolution/icons; but the icons for "delete mail item", "next mail item" and "previous mail item", for example, are missing.

I tried installing an icon theme package and this did not fix the problem. (In fact, I see no difference in appearance in *any* application following the install.)

Comment: Follow this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230778/ubuntu-20-04-applications-menu-has-no-icons-but-can-launch-softwares-from-the-s/1230850#1230850

Comment: Tried that solution - no change. Emphasize that desktop icons - both in the Applications menu and in the dock - are fine. The missing icons are within specific applications - see above - and are missing from toolbars and menus within those applications. In addition, the tools in the toolbars are still active - the tool tip pops up and clicking on the apparently blank portion of the toolbar functions as expected.

Comment: UPDATE: After installing Tweaks, I used it to change two Appearance themes: Applications (changed from Adwaita to Ambiance) and Icons (changed from Adwaita to Ubuntu-mono-dark.) ALL of the affected applications (including, surprisingly, LibreOffice) are now displaying icons in toolbars and menus.

Comment: I already had my applications on Ambiance and icons on Ubuntu-mono-dark and still there was no system tray. I see only the sound and network menu in top right corner along with keyboard language selection. There used to be application icons, like TeamViewer, MS Teams, Discord... now there's nothing.