# current running applications not showing in side menu bar in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, and in Ubuntu 20.04 when I am running any app then icon of that app is not showing in sidebar.

[image]

in this Image we can see that few applications are running but their icons are not showing in right sidebar.
How can I solve this issue ?

version:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Release:    20.04

Codename:   focal

Comment: First try resetting the dock to defaults: `gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock`, then log out then back in. If issue persists, then indicate what extensions you have installed - use the tool `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` (may need to install that first) to see which ones you have, and which ones are system extensions or not.

Comment: I did reset dock to default then did re-login, same issue is happening .

Comment: It is an issue with your account settings. It will not happen in a fresh account. Problem, of course, is to isolate where the problem lies in your current account configuration. I suppose you also tried disabling/removing any custom extensions?

Comment: I don't remember but I have installed some tools only. but problem is from starting (on fresh installation). after opening some applications dock is not updated with icons but after opening applications when I shift dock position from left to right or vice versa it get updated with that icons that I have currently opened.

Answer (score 5):

for me the problem was resolved with running:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell exactly from your graphic but have you set to `auto hide` the dock?

The Dock will automatically hide when any window overlaps or gets in close proximity to it.

Go to > Settings > Appearance > Dock

[image]

If it is set, then unset it by clicking on the slider
(in my example graphic it is shown to be set)

Comment: On the graphic, it appears as if the Dock is moved to the right. However, only the "Show applications" icon (on the bottom right) appears. None of the icons on the dock appear.

Comment: yes, I had moved dock to right side.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2: The correct answer is here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1277165/1384416**

Leaving info below on the off chance that it is also useful...

---

I had the same problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Turns out that Gnome Tweaks had Ubuntu dock turned off.

1. Bring up the application launcher (for lack of a better way of describing it, hit the "windows" key")
2. Type "tweaks"
3. In the extensions section, find "Ubuntu dock" and switch it on.

[Ensure Ubuntu Dock is turned on in the extensions section of "tweaks"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7smyb.png)

If you don't already have the tweak tool, you can install it like this - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux/

**EDIT 1:** Toggling "Ubuntu Dock" seems to make the sidebar update on toggle, but it holds it's state after that. Can't seem to get it to live update as applications are opened / closed. Further investigation and tinkering required.